# can we execute unix command from oracle10g procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Oracle10g in unix machine

I have a requirement to execute the unix command in procedure how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
BEGIN
     DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
    job_name        => 'SHELL_JOB',
    repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=2',
    job_type         => 'EXECUTABLE',
    job_action       => '/u01/app/oracle/admin/tools/shell_job.sh',
    enabled          => TRUE,
    comments         => 'Perform stuff'
);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI) package from Oracle.  There is also an open source set of packages for doing this.  You can find those [here](http://plsqlexecoscomm.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

If DBMS_SCHEDULER isn't enough for you and you need to run commands within the context of other PL/SQL code, then you will need to look into [calling External Procedures](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_extern_proc.htm#g1040439).

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share about an alternative approach for calling operating system commands. In this approach a simple web-service interface is setup for calling os commands from SQL or PL/SQL. Details about this approach can be found here:

[Run Operating System (OS) Command in Oracle PL/SQL: A Web Service Approach](https://moizmuhammad.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/run-os-command-in-oracle-plsql/)

Using this approach, a step-by-step description about how to invoke SQL*Loader from SQL is also described here:

[Run Oracle SQL-Loader from SQL or PL/SQL](https://moizmuhammad.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/run-oracle-sqlloader-from-sql-or-plsql/)

Please note that in the above approach the web-service is defined in Python. Python comes pre-installed with most common linux distribution (including Oracle Linux), however if you are on windows platform then you may need to install the python 2.7.3

Comment: Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is required that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.